# Cron job,crontab

Tags: cron

I need help. I must to do next: make cron job for root and save the packets in /var/log on home directory for test user every 2 hours with date stamp,and that file must have user and group for test user?

Comment: Is this homework?

Comment: yes,actually preparing for a job

Comment: create a script to get packets and save that with the time stamp every 2hrs from a cromjob

Answer (score 1):

You can use `tcpdump` tool to achieve this.

Script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

echo "$(date +%x_%H:%M:%S:%N)" > /var/log/info.txt

echo " " >> /var/log/koko.txt

tcpdump -c 10 -w /tmp/info.pcap -i eno1 tcp && \

tcpdump -r /tmp/info.pcap >> /var/log/info.txt
```

Make script executable with `chmod +x sniffer.sh`

Then add the job to cron:

1. Open cron editor as root:

   ```
   sudo crontab -e
   ```
2. Add the line

   ```
   0 */2 * * * /path/to/sniffer.sh
   ```

Explanation:

- `echo "$(date +%x_%H:%M:%S:%N)" > /var/log/koko.txt`: echo the date into the output file
- `echo " " >> /var/log/koko.txt`: separate the date from other conten with a line
- `tcpdump -c 10 -w /tmp/info.pcap -i eno1 tcp &&`: Capture 10 packets from interface `eno1` (can be lefet out, in which case it will capture from all interfaces) and write to a file and if successful do the next command,
- `tcpdump -r /tmp/info.pcap >> /var/log/koko.txt`: read from that file and write to a the `info.txt` file.

Answer (score 0):

create bash,python or perl script and make excute every hours by adding this into crontab

```
0 */2 * * * python script.py
```

or

```
0 */2 * * * /etc/bashscript.sh ....
```

Comment: ok,i must make a new script for root and than make this 0 * /2 * * * root /var/log/newscript >> /home/ ?

Comment: Read `man crontab` for more info.